# Error "Badly formatted index, after interpolation still contains placeholder"

Tags: indexing, format, logstash, filebeat

While trying to collect logs form Filebeat filestream into Logstash i've stuck with an error generetate by Logstash:

> Badly formatted index, after interpolation still contains placeholder: [%{[fields.log_type]}-%{[agent.version]}-2023.03.29] (or whatever i try)

Initially thinking there was an index format syntax error in output section of Logstash conf.d file i've spend a lot of time trying to modify it (especially *index* field) - with no luck:

```
...
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "https://IP:9200" ]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    manage_template => false
    ssl => true
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/certs/http_ca.crt"
    user => "logstash_internal"
    password => "XXX"
  }
 # stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I understood, anyhow modifying Logstash config - the problem was somewhere else out there:
The filebeate.yml inputs section should include:

```
  fields_under_root: true
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-general-options.html#_fields_under_root

And the error was gone. And the index was applied by LS.
May be it'll help to someone else. Good luck.
Alexandr.